# Spring aop doesn't run when project starts

Tags: spring-boot, aop

I'v implemented a spring-boot aop demo and it runs well, but when I want to use it to load some resource when the project starts, it doesn't work somehow

Aop:

```
package com.neo.mysql;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

/**
 * Created by li_weia on 2017/7/6.
 */
@Aspect
@Component
public class DynamicDataSourceAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(VendorSource)")
    public void beforeSwitchDS(JoinPoint point){

        //获得当前访问的class
        Class<?> className = point.getTarget().getClass();

        //获得访问的方法名
        String methodName = point.getSignature().getName();
        //得到方法的参数的类型
        Class[] argClass = ((MethodSignature)point.getSignature()).getParameterTypes();
        String dataSource = DataSourceContextHolder.DEFAULT_DS;
        try {
            // 得到访问的方法对象
            Method method = className.getMethod(methodName, argClass);

            // 判断是否存在@DS注解
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(VendorSource.class)) {
                VendorSource annotation = method.getAnnotation(VendorSource.class);
                // 取出注解中的数据源名
                dataSource = annotation.value();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // 切换数据源
        DataSourceContextHolder.setDB(dataSource);

    }


    @After("@annotation(VendorSource)")
    public void afterSwitchDS(JoinPoint point){

        DataSourceContextHolder.clearDB();

    }
}
```

The VendorSource annotation:

```
package com.neo.mysql;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

/**
 * Created by li_weia on 2017/7/6.
 */
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface VendorSource {
    String value() default "vendor-master";
}
```

It runs well here, I can successfully change datasource by annotation:

```
package com.neo.web;

import com.neo.entity.SiteEntity;
import com.neo.mapper.ClassMappingDao;
import com.neo.mysql.VendorSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    private final ClassMappingDao siteMapper;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public UserController(ClassMappingDao siteMapper) {
        this.siteMapper = siteMapper;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getSites")
    @VendorSource("vendor-read")
    public List<SiteEntity> getUsers() {
        return siteMapper.getAllSite();
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work here, the aop method is not invoked at all:

```
package com.neo.component;

import com.neo.entity.SiteEntity;
import com.neo.mapper.ClassMappingDao;
import com.neo.mysql.VendorSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by li_weia on 2017/7/7.
 */
@Component
public class TestComponent{
    private final ClassMappingDao userMapper;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public TestComponent(ClassMappingDao userMapper) {
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
        init();
    }

    @VendorSource("vendor-read")
    public void init() {
        List<SiteEntity> sites = userMapper.getAllSite();
        for(SiteEntity site: sites){
            System.out.println(site.getSite());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the TestComponent can be initialized successfully, it seems like the default datasource is used and the annotation doesn't work at all

Comment: How did you enable AOP?

Comment: with Aspect and Component annotation, spring boot will enable it automatically

Comment: Only if you've `spring-boot-starter-aop` on the classpath, then it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the annotation, like so:

```
@Before("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.neo.mysql.VendorSource)")
private void whatever() {}
```

Also, as mentioned in my comment above, you need to have `spring-boot-starter-aop` on classpath. Maybe you already do, but since you didn't say, it's worth mentioning.

**Edit**:

I didn't notice the real problem before, I wasn't paying attention.

1. Spring AOP only triggers if you make calls from another class. This is because Spring needs to be able to intercept the call and run the pointcut. Calling the method from constructor is not going to do anything.
2. You can do a hackish workaround. Create a `@PostConstruct void postConstruct() {}` method in your class (not constructor), autowire `ApplicationContext`, and then do `MyClassWithInitMethod myClass = context.getBean(MyClassWithInitMethod.class)` in the `postConstruct` method. Then call the method on `myClass`, and AOP will kick in.

Frankly, I didn't previously check what you are doing in your pointcut, and it's a terrible idea. When multiple threads run, they are going to overwrite the static context, and create a race-condition that you'll then create another question for. **Don't do it!** Use the factory pattern instead, and inject the `DataSourceFactory` in the classes that now have the annotation.

Comment: did as you say, but the init method still doesn't work as expected while the controller works well

Comment: The `init` method is in a class that's in a separate package. Are you scanning it?

Comment: yes, spring boot does it for me, and I can see the sites have been printed by `System.out.println(site.getSite())`, but from another database

Comment: sure I scan it, and when the application starts, I can see the `init` runs automatically(which means this component has been scanned, right?), but the application doesn't go to the break point I set in class `DynamicDataSourceAspect`, and the message printed comes from wrong database

Comment: btw, I create a `DataSourceContextHolder` with a threadlocal filed to hold the datasource, so I think it will works right when multiple threads run. Factory pattern way was the first plan ,but it can lead to a little more complicated

Comment: @Levy, thread local can lead to resource leak if you don't clean it afterwards. Don't say I didn't warn you.

Comment: yeah, that's what After for.  Actually, I'm really thinking about factory way, but I don't know how to do so that the application can change the datasource automatically