# Facing issue with Guava Cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, google-guava-cache

I'm using Google Guava Cache + Spring cache abstraction for caching purpose.
I'm trying to make use of Guava's Loading Cache interface for the same.

I know Spring provides support for Guava Cache, but I was wondering whether I can make use of spring's cacheable annotation alongwith Loading Cache?

Basically I wanted to keep the business layer separate from the Cache.

Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Has any of the answers helped you? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Guava Cache is deprecated. If you'd existing code, that'd be another matter, but for new code, use [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).
2. Put a `@Cacheable("myCacheName")` on the method that you want to cache the return value for.
3. Put a `@EnableCaching` on your application class if using Spring Boot, otherwise on some `@Configuration` class.
4. Set the spec in `application.properties` if using Spring Boot, like so: `spring.cache.caffeine.spec=maximumSize=10000,expireAfterWrite=5m`. If not using Boot, use `@PropertySources` annotation on the same class as in #3 above.
5. Add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache` and `com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine` to your build file. If not using Boot, you'll need to set up the dependencies differently.

You're done.

Comment: the ideal way of doing caching in Spring, but loading caches provide additional flexibity

Answer (score 0):

So you want both butter and jam. Okay. I will help you use loading cache along with keeping caching logic separate.

Consider you have a service class `SampleServiceImpl` which implements `SampleService` interface.

Service interface:

```
public interface SampleService {
    User getUser(int id);
}
```

Service Implementation:

```
@Service
public class SampleServiceImpl implements SampleService {

    public User getUser(int id) {
        // fetch user from database
        return user;
    }
}
```

Create one more class `SampleServiceCache`

```
public class SampleServiceCache extends ServiceCacheImpl {

    @Autowired
    public SampleServiceCache(int expiryTime, int maximumSize) {

        loadingCache =
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(maximumSize).expireAfterAccess(expiryTime, TimeUnit.HOURS).build(
                        new CacheLoader<Integer, User>() {

                            @Override
                            public User load(@Nonnull Integer userId) {
                                return SampleServiceCache.super.getUser(userId);
                            }
                        });
    }
    @Override
    public User getUser(int userId) {
        return loadingCache.getUnchecked(userId);
    }
}
```

In you bean config:

```
@Bean
public SampleService sampleService() {
    return new SampleServiceCache(expiry, maxSize);
}
```

The day you want to remove cache, you have to do two things:
1. Remove the cache class.
2. Change bean config to return actual implementation object rather than cache implementation object.

P.S. You can define multiple loading caches for different behaviors say user retrieval, article retrieval, etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Cache abstraction.

Comment: You can not decouple the code if you use @Cacheable. And hence you won't be able to take benefits from loading cache

Comment: I don't think you know what decouple means.

Comment: @cacheable handles caching declaratively. So, there is no way you can use Cacheable annotation with loading cache. You can post an answer if you think there is one

Comment: also cacheable starts giving pain too early, you will have to use aspectj if you want to cache calls within same class(AOP), complicated spells to generate key, storing cache names(they are compile time constants)

Comment: If you're paid by the hour, the above code would be fine. Otherwise, declarative caching, preferably using JCache, is the way to go. Calls within same class is not a caching issue, and you don't need AspectJ for that. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961611/839733)

Comment: why use hackish ways when there are cleaner ways

Comment: would love to see some code from you(would get to learn), pros of jcache(& declarative caching) over loading cache, btw google does provide guava cache(deprecated, now use caffeine instead) that fits into this declarative model. But just think why have they created loading cache.